# Warning: Extra attributes from the server using Custom Web Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

in my company we have a component library build with stencil. And now we want to move some websites to next.js.
I created a new next.js project and referenced the needes javascript files for my web-components.
The components are displayed but i get the warning:
"Warning: Extra attributes from the server [...]"
Can someone explain why this occurs and maybe how to tell next.js there is nothing wrong happening?

The full Error is:

```
Extra attributes from the server: class
    at my-ui-icon
    at a
    at li
    at ul
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at nav
    at div
    at Navbar (webpack-internal:///./components/navbar.js:35:157)
    at div
    at Layout (webpack-internal:///./components/layout.js:37:157)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:21:24)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ErrorBoundary.js:26:47)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:86:23)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:258:5)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:754:24)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:893:25)
```

The "class" attribute is in the shadowDom.

Comment: Can you also add your `Navbar` component code please?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue just now.

In my case, `html` and `body` tags were present in both the root `app/layout.tsx` file and a `app/[locale]/layout.tsx` file. Removing them from the latter solved the problem.

I also found this link from NEXT.js that lists other, common reasons one might see this issue: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Also, I found this interesting discussion with the same problem and multiple possible solutions:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/22388

Hope this helps.